# SAF(Storage Access Framework) in pyjnius in python for Android 10 and higher

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, pyjnius

I am using Pydroid3. I am making an practice app in which a button will clicked then SAF will open to choose image. Image will select by user and selected image will show.

But image is not showing, why? I don't know. Code is not making any error. But after selecting an image SAF remove but image doesn't show if you say for permission then permission already given to my python ide.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from jnius import autoclass,cast
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ImagePickerApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = self.create_layout()
        return layout

    def create_layout(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10, padding=10)
        
        image = Image(source='default_image.png')
        pick_image_button = Button(text='Pick Image', on_press=self.pick_image)
        
        layout.add_widget(image)
        layout.add_widget(pick_image_button)

        return layout

    def pick_image(self, instance):
        # Use jnius to access Android Intent for picking images
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
        Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')

        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.setType("image/*")

        current_activity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        current_activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0) # This is returning None
        
    def on_activity_result(self, requestCode, resultCode, intent):
        # Handle the result of the image picking
        if requestCode == 0 and resultCode == -1:
            # -1 means RESULT_OK
            image_uri = intent.getData()
            # Process the selected image URI as needed
            # Update the displayed image, for example:
            self.root.children[0].source =str( image_uri)

    def snackbar(self, message):
        Snackbar(text=message).open()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImagePickerApp().run()
```

How to solve this problem?